# Replacing NA's with relevant values

Tags: regression, machine-learning, missing-data

I have the below information for around 1000 stores. 
[image]

The columns competition distance, competitionOpenSince , Promo2Since columns have NA's.

1.Promo2SinceWeek/Year is missing only for stores that did not run the promotion(Promo2=0).

2.Competition related columns are missing in random.

All these columns are specific to a store. Different stores will have different values. replacing a missing value by taking the mean/median of all other stores does not make sense to me.

I want to fit a linear regression/ regression trees model to predict sales. I really need some expert suggestions/ideas to handle these NA's with the appropriate method.

If required, I am ready to add the dataset here

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you are looking for ways to impute the missing values.

Please take a look at the following [article](http://r-statistics.co/Missing-Value-Treatment-With-R.html) which gives you a few different strategies for missing values. MICE works well in many cases, but it depends on your particular use case.